# Flask Middleware to be Express-js like

Tags: flask, wsgi, middleware

I wonder if it's possible to attach a middleware/function for a specific route like express js. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application

In my understanding, it seems that flask(WSGI) middleware applies to all request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent pattern is a route decorator. Flask has [some docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/) about it. It is pretty flexible, you can validate anything in HTTP request and change the response based on that.

For example, `Flask-Login` has the [`@login_required`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/1e7fa7ec9bf09d76c83edbf5709b322cb8b8449c/flask_login.py#L763) decorator to add a user authentication step before the route is called.